# Scala optional pattern matching

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

I find myself frequently using pattern matching that returns an `Option` with the no match case returning `None`, e.g.

```scala
x match {
    case A(a) => Some(a)
    case B(b) => Some(b)
    case _ => None
}
```

I can imagine simplifying this using

```scala
object MaybeMatchImplicits {
    implicit class MaybeMatcher[A](val underlying: A) extends AnyVal {
        @inline 
        def maybeMatch[B](f: PartialFunction[A, B]): Option[B] = f.lift.apply(underlying)
    }
}
```

which allows

```
scala> import MaybeMatchImplicits._
import MaybeMatchImplicits._

scala> 5 maybeMatch { case 5 => 'good }
res0: Option[Symbol] = Some('good)

scala> 6 maybeMatch { case 5 => 'good }
res1: Option[Symbol] = None
```

I am wondering if this approach hides any gotchas and/or if there is a simpler/better/more idiomatic mechanism for doing this in Scala 2.11+.

**Update:** The goal is to handle arbitrary computation on the rhs of matches, which makes exception-based solutions undesirable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Idiomatic:

```
scala> case class A(a: Int) ; case class B(b: String)
defined class A
defined class B

scala> def f(x: Any) = Option(x) collect { case A(a) => a ; case B(b) => b }
f: (x: Any)Option[Any]

scala> f(42)
res0: Option[Any] = None

scala> f(A(42))
res1: Option[Any] = Some(42)

scala> f(B("ok"))
res2: Option[Any] = Some(ok)
```

Alternatively:

```
scala> import PartialFunction.{cond => when, condOpt => whenever}
import PartialFunction.{cond=>when, condOpt=>whenever}

scala> def f(x: Any) = whenever(x) { case A(a) => a ; case B(b) => b }
f: (x: Any)Option[Any]

scala> f(42)
res3: Option[Any] = None

scala> f(A(42))
res4: Option[Any] = Some(42)

scala> f(B("ok"))
res5: Option[Any] = Some(ok)
```

Answer (score 3):

## Collect from Option

Use `get` method (see the implementation given below) which wraps the given  value around option and then collects required value.

Wrap the value using option and then collect what ever you want to collect.

```
Option(x: Any).collect { case 1 => 1 }
```

or

```
x get { case 2 => 2 } // get implementation is given below
```

**Scala REPL**

```
scala> Option(1).collect { case 1 => 1 }
res0: Option[Int] = Some(1)

scala> Option(2).collect { case str: String => "bad" }
<console>:12: error: scrutinee is incompatible with pattern type;
 found   : String
 required: Int
       Option(2).collect { case str: String => "bad" }
                                     ^

scala> Option(2: Any).collect { case str: String => "bad" }
res2: Option[String] = None

scala> Option(2: Any).collect { case 2 => "bad" }
res3: Option[String] = Some(bad)
```

## Nicer API using Implicit Class

```
implicit class InnerValue[A](value: A) {
  def get[B](pf: PartialFunction[Any, B]): Option[B] = Option(value) collect pf
}
```

**Scala REPL**

```
scala> implicit class InnerValue[A](value: A) {
     |   def get[B](pf: PartialFunction[Any, B]): Option[B] = Option(value) collect pf
     | }
defined class InnerValue

scala> 2.get { case 2 => 2}
res5: Option[Int] = Some(2)

scala> 2.get { case 3 => 2}
res6: Option[Int] = None
```

Now you can just `invoke` get method and pass the partial function. Now you may get a value wrapped in Some or will get None.

Notice that the above API (get method) is not type safe, you can do

```
 2.get { case str: String => str }
```

Which returns None.

Now if you want typesafe make the following change

## Type safety

```
 implicit class InnerValue[A](value: A) {
  def get[B](pf: PartialFunction[A, B]): Option[B] = Option(value) collect pf
 }
```

Notice in the partial function the input parameter type is `A` instead of Any.

Now, when you do

```
2.get { case str: String => str }
```

You will get compilation error.

```
scala>      2.get { case str: String => str }
<console>:15: error: scrutinee is incompatible with pattern type;
 found   : String
 required: Int
            2.get { case str: String => str }
```

### Get around the compilation error

You can get around the compilation error by doing following

```
scala> (2: Any) get { case str: String => str}
res16: Option[String] = None
```

Comment: This is the first time I'm seeing the `(2: Any)` syntax. Can you provide some details on this it's behavior or perhaps a scala-lang link? Also, ignoring the syntax differences between `x get {...}` and `x maybeMatch {...}`, what's the advantage of the former?

Comment: @Sim by doing `2: Any` you request compiler to consider 2 as Any instead of Int. Using standard scala lib you can go ahead doing `Option(x: Any).collect { case 1 => 1 }`. get uses option and collect. `get` and `maybeMatch` do the same. but differ in implementation

Comment: If we have no problem with `PartialFunction.condOpt("foo" : Any) { case 5 => 'good }` why can't we hide the `(... : Any)` in the implementation of an implicit class to gain cleaner calling syntax?

Comment: BTW, wrapping the value in `Option()` has a subtle problem with `null` values, e.g., `Option(null) collect { case null => 'good }` won't match. That's why it seems better to directly use the partial function and not transform the value to be matched.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this:

```
def trial(a:Any, f:Any => Any) = try Some(f(a)) catch {case _:MatchError => None}

implicit class BetterAny(a:Any) {
   def betterMatch(f:Any => Any) = trial(a, f)
}

// some example classes
case class A(i:Int)
case class B(s:String)
```

On the REPL:

```
scala> A(1) betterMatch {case A(a) => a; case B(b) => b}
res11: Option[Any] = Some(1)

scala> 2 betterMatch {case A(a) => a; case B(b) => b}
res12: Option[Any] = None
```

Comment: That's a poor solution for two reasons. First, you cannot be sure that `MatchError` is thrown at the top level of the partial function as opposed to deep inside the call stack of one of the rhs of a matched case. Second, exceptions are quite slow.

Comment: I'm assuming that your match will  be simple cases like `A(a) => a` without computation. Of course the solution will depend on the actual `f`.

Comment: I am looking for a solution for arbitrary rhs computation just as with `match`.